# TBitmap SaveToFile Seems Slow in windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, io

I run the same code below on Multi-boot machine windows 7 and windows 10, and the benchmarks show slow SaveToFile operation in Windows 10

Windows 10 500, 953, 875, 688, 578, 750, 453

Windows 7  109, 125, 109, 110, 125, 140, 125

```
var
  I, Tick: integer;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  Bitmap.SetSize(500,500);
  Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
  Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsDiagCross;
  Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clRed;
  Tick := GetTickCount;
  for I := 0 to 100 do
  begin
    SetBkColor(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255)));
    Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, 500, 500));
    Bitmap.SaveToFile(IntToStr(I)+'.bmp');
  end;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetTickCount-Tick));
  Bitmap.Free;
end;
```

I think SaveToFile works different in windows 10 it waits till all bitmaps are saved, in case of windows 7 it works like background task, if that is true how to make SaveToFile works as in windows 7.

Update

as @ForguesR mentioned the slow down comes from Windows 10 defender after disabling it, I got better result 187, 171, 172, 178, 188, 156, 187 , Windows 7 defender does not affect saving, I don't know about windows 8.
Is there API or a way to stop windows 10 defender from checking and slowing saving operation?

Comment: Is Windows Defender disabled?  That might be the reason for the slow down.

Comment: "*in windows 10 it waits till all bitmaps are saved, in case of windows 7 it works like background task*" - that is not how `SaveToFile()` works, and never has. `SaveToFile()` is synchronous, it does not return until the file has been completely written to and closed. When the loop ends (assuming no exception is raised), all 101 files have been finished.

Comment: Also, `GetTickCount()` is not always accurate, so consider using [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) instead. And be sure to time each operation inside the loop, not just `SaveToFile()` by itself. Other things happen behind the scenes when you make changes to a Canvas. Try caching the `TRect` locally so you don't recalculate it each time, and replacing `Canvas.FillRect()` with `Windows.FillRect()` directly. If you still think `SaveToFile()` is the culprit of the slowdown, step into it with the debugger and find out what it is really doing.

Comment: @ForguesR I turned off Windows 10 defender and got better results 187, 171, 172, 178, 188, 156, 187

Answer (score 1):

You are running the same program on the same hardware but with a different OS.  Starting from there it was obvious that there was something in Windows 10 slowing it down.  As you found out, by disabling Windows 10 Defender you get almost the same performance.

Fortunately, you can not "control" an antivirus from your code.  If that would be possible spreading a virus would be an easy task.

Comment: It is also worth noting that having two OS-es on same computer does not guarantee for them to have same performance even if both of the OS-es in question are of the same version. Why? Each OS needs its own system partition and unless these partitions have been created in a way that they exists "side by side". But most often partitions are created in a way that they are place one after another which means that the partition that is closer to the beginning of the hard drive space is getting better performance.

Comment: @SilverWarior Good point but I don't think it would impact the performance in a magnitude of 6x to 8x slower.